# How to Set a Fixed Range of Data for a Mixed Type Chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I have a graph of rows in a combined / combined chart type (row and slash), I want to define a fixed data scale for row and for slash, how do I set the default values?

[Here is my existing code.](https://codepen.io/junedchhipa/pen/YJQKOy)

```
<script>
var options = {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'line',
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Website Blog',
        type: 'column',
        data: [440, 505, 414, 671, 227, 413, 201, 352, 752, 320, 257, 160]
    }, {
        name: 'Social Media',
        type: 'line',
        data: [23, 42, 35, 27, 43, 22, 17, 31, 22, 22, 12, 16]
    }],
    stroke: {
        width: [0, 4]
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Traffic Sources'
    },
    // labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug","Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    labels: ['01 Jan 2001', '02 Jan 2001', '03 Jan 2001', '04 Jan 2001', '05 Jan 2001', '06 Jan 2001', '07 Jan 2001', '08 Jan 2001', '09 Jan 2001', '10 Jan 2001', '11 Jan 2001', '12 Jan 2001'],
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yaxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Website Blog',
        },
    }, {
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Social Media'
        }
    }]
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#chart"),
    options
);

chart.render();
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by fixed data-set? Do you want to fix the range of y-axis?

Comment: put the Y scale fixed, I want to set a value for it

Comment: Have you tried yaxis.min and yaxis.max in both yaxis in your example? That way, you will be able to control the lowest and highest values of y-axis

Comment: What is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the axis range by specifying `yaxis.min` and `yaxis.max` in the following way.

```
yaxis: [{
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    title: {
        text: 'Website Blog',
    },
}, {
    min: 10,
    max: 200,
    opposite: true,
    title: {
        text: 'Social Media'
    }
}]
```